# Why am I receiving 'Error TS1146' in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn Angular and am going through the Angular.io Tutorial. I think I've reproduced the Tutorial code exactly, but the compiler keeps giving me error at line 4, TS1146: Declaration expected. (I've also included the ../hero.ts file referenced at line 2, in case that's causing the problem).

Originally, everything had been working fine, and then I added a new Component through the Angular CLI (Windows 10), i.e.

> _>ng generate component messages

(as per the next lesson in the tutorial), and then suddenly started getting the error message.

```
1 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
2 import { Hero } from '../hero';
3
4 @Input() hero: Hero;
5
6 @Component({
7 selector: 'app-hero-detail',
8 templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
9 styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.scss']
10 })
11 export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
12
13      constructor() { }
14
15      ngOnInit() {
16      }
17
18    }
```

In the ../hero.ts file:

```
1 export class Hero {
2 id: number;
3 name: string;
4 }
```

Comment: line 4 should be moved into class definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Input should be placed within the component definition as follows,

```
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() hero: Hero;
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it!